# What does ON [PRIMARY] mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm creating an SQL setup script and I'm using someone else's script as an example.  Here's an example of the script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[be_Categories](
    [CategoryID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_be_Categories_CategoryID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ParentID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_be_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Does anyone know what the ON [PRIMARY] command does?

Answer (score 316, accepted):

When you create a database in Microsoft SQL Server you can have multiple file groups, where storage is created in multiple places, directories or disks. Each file group can be named. The PRIMARY file group is the default one, which is always created, and so the SQL you've given creates your table ON the PRIMARY file group.

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) for the full syntax.

Comment: This also means it's usually **useless and can be safely removed** from the script.

Comment: Yes, in the same way you can just omit variable initializations to 0 and false, because it's just the default, right?

Comment: @MarkSowul Unless you have a good reason to use this to optimize performance, yes, it's fine to omit it and let the default happen. (Hence the "usually" MGOwen included.) Initializing variables to `0` or `false` is about ensuring that your code is operating in a known state, which is a logical and correctness concern and not an optimization concern.

Comment: MSDN link seems to be taking to a download page instead.

Comment: I see the `ON PRIMARY` syntax twice in the script - One for the table and another for the table constraint. What does it signify in case of the table constraint in terms of storage? It sounds irrelevant or redundant to me. Syntactically, it should have been sufficient to mention it once at the table level or is it really possible to store the table on PRIMARY file group and table constraint data on NON-PRIMARY file group?

Comment: Here is the actual [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) link. The one in the answer no longer works and I cannot edit the post !

Answer (score 46):

It refers to which filegroup the object you are creating resides on.  So your Primary filegroup could reside on drive D:\ of your server.  you could then create another filegroup called Indexes.  This filegroup could reside on drive E:\ of your server.

Comment: Will it have a negative performance impact if I store the table on PRIMARY file group and table constraint or index data structure on a different file group?

Comment: @RBT There are lots of variables that can affect this, and usually lots of answers will begin with "It depends but..." see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/when-should-nonclustered-indexes-be-stored-on-separate-filegroups and related questions

Answer (score 20):

ON [PRIMARY] will create the structures on the "Primary" filegroup.  In this case the primary key index and the table will be placed on the "Primary" filegroup within the database.

Answer (score 12):

Please be aware about an important behavior related to file groups.

Using OP's SQL Script you can *never* mention two different file groups i.e. one for storing your data rows and the other for index data structure. This is *not* allowed.

This is due to the fact that the index being created in this case is a clustered Index on the column which is primary key for the table. **Metadata of the clustered index** and **data rows of a table** can *never* be stored in two different file groups.

My database has two file groups:

1. **PRIMARY**
2. **SECONDARY**

Now take a look at the below script and execute it via SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS). Now something will happen against our expectation.

It will store the table's row data as well as the *metadata* pertaining to the clustered index *both* on the **PRIMARY** file group itself. This is happening even when I've mentioned a *different* file group (**[SECONDARY]**) for storing the table's row data. I wrote such an script deliberately to test the behvior:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[be_Categories](
    [CategoryID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_be_Categories_CategoryID]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ParentID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_be_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [SECONDARY]
GO
```

More interestingly, the above script runs to completion *without* any error. Frankly speaking, I was expecting a run-time error as I had given two *different* file groups. SQL Server does the trick behind the scene silently *without* throwing any error.

**NOTE**: But yes, the index can reside on different file groups in case of *non-clustered* indexes.

SQL script shown below creates a non-clustered index. The non-clustered index will get created on **[SECONDARY]** file group while the table's data rows reside on **[PRIMARY]** file group:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Categories] ON [dbo].[be_Categories]
(
    [CategoryName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Secondary]
GO
```

You can get more information [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2626/101434) about how storing non-clustered indexes on a different file group can *boost* query performance.