# SQL create table "ON"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In one of my Client code I have seen,

```
Create table Students (id int, name varchar 100) on PRIMARY
```

What is the importance of **"on"** in create table.?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why down vote it... i did not see that post when I searched in stackoverflow. Then how can I know this question is there??? This is not good. I can delete the post. but downvotting is not a good practice for this post.

Comment: why your question taged as `SQL-Server` and `mysql`.

Comment: i thought this query is common in my sql and mssql...

Answer (score 2):

Specifies the partition scheme or filegroup on which the table is stored

[CREATE TABLE (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

When you create a database in Microsoft SQL Server you can have multiple file groups, where storage is created in multiple places, directories or disks. Each file group can be named. The PRIMARY file group is the default one, which is always created, and so the SQL you've given creates your table ON the PRIMARY file group.

See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798213/what-does-on-primary-mean)

Comment: The same link specified in comment...

Comment: I also saw the post Mijoe... :)

Comment: but i dont downvote it. Thank you for your attempt.