# On [PRIMARY] and [OTHERS] and obscure option [SORT_IN_TEMPDB]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I read this post
[What does ON [PRIMARY] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798213/what-does-on-primary-mean)

and I wonder how I can get the text `"PRIMARY"` or any other file group names in use by using SQL scripts. 
I also look into the syntax of `CREATE table` and see `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` and try searching for it with queries in MS SMS but can't find where it is either.

Comment: I will be voted down till banned. please help me quick before I go. :(

Comment: please clarify your question, it  is not clear, what are you looking for, you wanna see word "Primary" in SSMS ? is it your target ? - voted it up for deleting voted down. .. keeping you between us.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'd like to know which view is storing the information of my database table that I can use to output the word "Primary" or "Your table is on Primary".

Comment: `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` is not a property of an index and does not persist; it must be specified on every `CREATE` or `ALTER` statement and is specific to that particular execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   select OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) as obj_name, fg.name as fg 
   from sys.partitions p inner join sys.allocation_units au 
           on au.container_id = p.hobt_id 
        inner join sys.filegroups fg 
           on fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id
   ```
2. SORT_IN_TEMPDB is the CREATE INDEX option: [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql)

> SORT_IN_TEMPDB = { ON | OFF } Applies to: SQL Server 2008 through SQL
>   Server 2017 and Azure SQL Database. Specifies whether to store
>   temporary sort results in tempdb. The default is OFF. ON The
>   intermediate sort results that are used to build the index are stored
>   in tempdb. This may reduce the time required to create an index if
>   tempdb is on a different set of disks than the user database. However,
>   this increases the amount of disk space that is used during the index
>   build.