# How to Convert SqlServer ON [PRIMARY] into Sqlalchemy Model?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have query in sqlserver and I wanted to write a model corresponding to it using sqlalchemy orm. I need to know how to convert ON [PRIMARY] into sqlalchemy.

Here is my query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserModel](
[userid] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[username] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[serialnumber] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Here is my model:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserModel'

    userid = Column('userid', Unicode(255))
    username = Column('username', Unicode(255))
    serialnumber = Column('serialnumber', Unicode(255))
```

Any suggestions, how would I achieve this
Currently I m getting the following error as below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|UserModel|UserModel could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'UserModel'
```

I know there there is no primary primary key defined in my model but the above query is working fine. So I wanted to translate the above query using sqlalchemy orm.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot translate the above DDL using most ORMs, at least directly, because [they expect Python objects to correspond to uniquely identifiable rows](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key) in the database. Now, if you know for sure that for example `UserModel.userid` uniquely identifies rows, you can instruct SQLAlchemy to use it as a "primary key":

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'UserModel'

    userid = Column('userid', Unicode(255))
    username = Column('username', Unicode(255))
    serialnumber = Column('serialnumber', Unicode(255))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'primary_key': [userid]
    }
```

Keep in mind that you've lied to the ORM and any consequences are on you.

As to defining the filegroup the table should be stored in using [`ON [PRIMARY]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you'll have to augment the [mssql dialect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html) a bit:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

# Add our custom dialect specific argument
Table.argument_for('mssql', 'on', None)

@compiles(CreateTable, 'mssql')
def compile_create_table(create, compiler, **kw):
    stmt = compiler.visit_create_table(create, **kw)
    filegroup = create.element.kwargs.get('mssql_on')

    if filegroup:
        stmt = stmt.rstrip()  # Prettier output, remove newlines
        filegroup = compiler.preparer.quote(filegroup)
        stmt = f"{stmt} ON {filegroup}\n\n"

    return stmt
```

and add the necessary table args to your model definition:

```
class UserModel(db.Model):
    ...
    __table_args__ = {
        'mssql_on': 'PRIMARY'
    }
```

You can verify that the resulting DDL is as desired:

```
In [4]: print(CreateTable(UserModel.__table__).compile(dialect=engine.dialect))

CREATE TABLE [UserModel] (
        userid NVARCHAR(255) NULL, 
        username NVARCHAR(255) NULL, 
        serialnumber NVARCHAR(255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Note that at least according to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798213/what-does-on-primary-mean) primary is the default and as such `ON [PRIMARY]` could just be omitted.