# If sql table exists create

Tags: sql

This question has been answered many times before but when I use the code, I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
                 AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema')
BEGIN
    // create..
END
```

My code

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'control_forecastscenario'
                 AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [rvfc].[control_forecastscenario]
    (
        [Scenario] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Active] [varchar](255) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The error is on Line 4

```
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc')
```

Comment: Looks like you need to finish off your BEGIN block with and END statement. Otherwise the statement ran fine for me.

Comment: And of course you need to create your rvfc schema beforehand

Comment: @RexHenderson thank you quick question do you think this method or incorporating a trigger would be more sufficient

Comment: I'm not clear what your goals are, but stay away from triggers if at all possible.

Comment: When OP clarifies his goals, I'll provide a better answer. Thanks

Comment: Your syntax as you have posted it here is correct for MS SQL, this is not reproducable as it is displayed, are you executing this from management studio or from a script or a code routine?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I am working in Microsoft Azure Studio

Comment: So @Yigan32 is this still a problem? The error suggests that only part of your query is executing, but with the information provided, we cannot replicate the issue. `IF NOT EXISTS ... BEGIN... CREATE TABLE ... END` is a very common reusable pattern for DDL scripts, it looks like you're doing the right thing.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller the only issue I still have is the ON PRIMARY I must keep it within the code but im getting an incorrect syntax on Primary

Comment: Do you have the `END` statement after the `ON PRIMARY`? The error means that something immediately after it is incorrect. But again, this is very strange, there is something you're not posting because what you have posted does work in a vanilla environment

Answer (score 1):

As a single query, the syntax you have posted works perfectly. You didn't include the `END` to your `BEGIN` block in the post, but we know that is not the issue because the error message would have had a different line number in it.

The following single expression will work:
*(I like to indent the BEGIN but it makes no difference to the execution)*

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'control_forecastscenario'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [rvfc].[control_forecastscenario](
        [Scenario] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Active] [varchar](255) NULL
    )
END
```

*Also note that I have omitted the `ON [PRIMARY]` as [that is the default file group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2798232/1690217) and if you are not managing multiple file groups then it is better not to include references to them in your code base.*

The only way to recreate your error is by trying to execute this as separate batched calls. This might happen if your business logic is executing a script in chunks or line by line, or if you have somehow built the query in a way that a batch terminator like `GO` or  `;` has been injected into the script.

The following will create your error.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'control_forecastscenario'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc')
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The same error will occur if a simi-colon in injected into the original script.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'control_forecastscenario'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc')
;
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [rvfc].[control_forecastscenario](
    [Scenario] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Active] [varchar](255) NULL
    )
END
```

---

In addressing some other comments, the existence of the schema `rvfc` is not in question here, nor are other common syntax issues because they would raise different error messages like this:

> Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> The specified schema name "rvfc" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

If you have executed this statement, omitting the `END` you would see a different line number, but the same message:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'control_forecastscenario'
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'rvfc') BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [rvfc].[control_forecastscenario](
    [Scenario] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Active] [varchar](255) NULL
    )
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

The message is the same because the `BEGIN` block *requires* closure with an `END` which makes the entire `BEGIN` block invalid. So `)` was the last valid character in the script, so that is the last place SQL can report the error.

---

> Please post your code that is executing the script for further assistance, otherwise this post should be closed as not reproducable.